# Javascript: Please help me convert this C function to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c

I have the following `C` function:

```
unsigned int DJBHash(char* str, unsigned int len)
{
   unsigned int hash = 5381;
   unsigned int i    = 0;

   for(i = 0; i < len; str++, i++)
   {
      hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + (*str);
   }

   return hash;
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to Javascript. I'm having trouble with the `(*str)` part of line 8

```
(`hash=((hash << 5) + hash) + (*str)`).
```

How can I *efficiently* convert my `javascript` string into the same representation as is done in `C`?

Here's what I've done sofar, but it's not working: when I add zero to "str", it simply appends a character "0" to my str.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function DJBHash(str,len){
        var hash=5381;
        var i=0;

        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                hash=((hash<<5)+hash)+(str+0);
        }
        return hash;
}
```

Comment: Hey, when I add zero to "str", it simply appends a character "0" to my str...

Comment: *"not working"* - certain phrases need to be banned on SO.

Comment: But why do you add zero to str?

Comment: I was hoping that would force Javascript to treat str as a numerical representation...

Comment: `parseInt(str)` would do it, but it's not what your c function does.

Comment: because it's not numeric, perhaps.

Comment: You can also compile C to Javascript using Emscripten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no pointers in Javascript. Treat the input as a string instead of a pointer to a string. The string has a length, so you don't need to send that as a parameter, and the string object has the `charCodeAt` method that you can use to get the character code of a specific character during the loop:

```
function DJBHash(str) {
  var hash = 5381;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return hash;
}
```

However, the C code might rely on the `int` to have a specific size (which is however not according to the C specifications), to use the overflow to limit the result to a specific number of bits. As Javascript doesn't have any integer type, you would have to use integer operations to limit the result in the same way. This would produce a 32 bit result:

```
function DJBHash(str) {
  var hash = 5381;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hash = (((hash << 5) + hash) + str.charCodeAt(i)) & 0xffffffff;
  }
  return hash;
}
```

Comment: it's the unsigned int of the whole string I want to add hash by, not just a char

Comment: @Eamorr: That's not what the original C code does. It loops through the characters in the string and uses the character code to construct the hash code. The `str` parameter is a pointer to a `char` (byte), so `*str` is the single `char` that it points to, and as the `str` pointer is changed in the loop, it will point to each `char` value in turn.

Comment: That should do the trick! Many thanks. I just hope I don't get too many collisions in my hash table using this DJBHash algorithm...

Comment: Actually, it's even worse — c char is signed. And even worse — the unicode string may give quite unusual for c char values ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `str.charCodeAt(i)`, not `str+0`.

Comment: Yep, but you can't do the str++ bit in Javascript

Comment: Actually, it's the unsigned int of the whole string I want to add hash by, not just a char.

Comment: Earmorr, What is unsigned int of the whole string? Whatever it is, it's not what your c function does.

Comment: missingno, you don't need to, you don't access string elements using pointer here.

Comment: I don't mind being downvoted, but what exactly the downvoter found offensive here? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the pointer shenanigans, and iterate using only `i`:

```
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
      hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + (str.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you may be disappointed in numeric value of charAt() :)

Comment: it's the unsigned int of the whole string I want to add hash by, not just a char